# Building a dictionary using two files

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I am very very new to python and I have been playing around to write a script using two files. File 1 contains a number of ID numbers such as:

```
1000012
1000015
1000046
1000047
1000050
1000072
1000076
100008
1000102
100013
```

The other file has few lines of single ID numbers followed by lines made of one ID number followed by other ID numbers which have a + or - at the end:

```
951450
8951670
8951800
8951863
8951889
9040311
9255087 147+ 206041- 8852164- 4458078- 1424812- 3631438- 8603144+ 4908786- 4780663+ 4643406+ 3061176- 7523696- 5876052- 163881- 6234800- 395660-
9255088 149+ 7735585+ 6359867+ 620034- 4522360- 2810885- 3705265+ 5966368- 7021344+ 9165926- 2477382+ 4015358- 2497281+ 9166415+ 6837601-
9255089 217+ 6544241+ 5181434+ 4625589+ 7433598+ 7295233+ 3938917+ 4109401+ 2135539+ 4960823+ 1838531+ 1959852+ 5698864+ 1925066+ 8212560+ 3056544+ 82N 1751642+ 4772695+ 2396528+ 2673866+ 2963754+ 5087444+ 977167+ 2892617- 7412278- 6920479- 2539680- 4315259- 8899799- 733101- 5281901- 7055760+ 8508290+ 8559218+ 7985985+ 6391093+ 2483783+ 8939632+ 3373919- 924346+ 1618865- 8670617+ 515619+ 5371996+ 2152211+ 6337329+ 284813+ 8512064+ 3469059+ 3405322+ 1415471- 1536881- 8034033+ 4592921+ 4226887- 6578783-
```

I want to build a dictionary using these two files. My script has to search inside File 2 for the ID numbers in File 1 and append those lines as values in which the key is the number in File 1. Therefore there may be more than one value for each key. I only want to search the lines in File 2 that have more than one number (if len(x) > 1).

the output would be something like: 1000047: 9292540 1000047+ 9126889+ 3490727- 8991434+ 4296324+ 9193432- 3766395+ 9193431+ 8949379- (I need to print each ID number in File1 as the key and as its value, the chunk of lines that contain that ID number as a whole)

Here is my -very wrong- script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('file1')
z = open('file2')
d = dict() # d is an empty dictionary

for l in f:
    p = l.rstrip()

d[p] = list()       # sets the keys in the dictionary as p (IDs with newline characters stripped)
y = z.readlines() # retrieves a string from the path file 
s = "".join(y)    # makes a string from y 
x = str.split(s)  #splits the path file at white spaces

if len(x) > 1:   # only the lines that include contigs IDs that were used to make another contig

    for lines in y:
        k = lines.rstrip()    
    w = tuple(x)    # convert list x into a tuple called w
    for i in w:         
        if i[:-1] in d:   
            d[p].append(k) 
print d
```

Comment: Please give an example of the desired output.

Comment: provide the desired output by editing the original question, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?? (I have not tested it ...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('file1')
z = open('file2')
d = dict() # d is an empty dictionary

for l in f.readlines():
    for l2 in z.readlines():
        if l.rstrip() in l2.rstrip():
            d[l] = l2
    z.seek(0, 0)

f.close()
z.close()
```

Here is a simpler version the same code, if you don't want to deal with the file pointer

```
f = open("file1")
z = open("file2")
d = dict() # d is an empty dictionary

file1_lines = f.readlines()
file2_lines = z.readlines()
for l in file1_lines:
    for l2 in file2_lines:
        if l.rstrip() in l2.rstrip():
            d[l] = l2

print d
f.close()
z.close()
```

Comment: Use `with open('file1') as f, open('file2') as z` for better file I/O.

Comment: This gives me the output:

{'1000012\n': '9279863\t663068- 3473145+ 2405965- 5379610- 9170289- 2670268+ 8176642+ 1000012- 616493+ 6290073+ 9004274+\n'} 

so it only searches for the first ID number in file1, but not the rest

Comment: Yes, after reading the file in the inner loop, the file pointer had to be restored to beginning of the file. I have updated the above code with seek to restore the file pointer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('file1')
z = open('file2')
d = dict() # d is an empty dictionary

for l in f:
    p = l.rstrip()
    d[p] = list()       # Change #1

f.close()
# Now we have a dictinary with the keys from file1 and empty lists as values
for line in z:
    items = item.split() # items will be a list from 1 line
    if len(items) > 1: # more than initial item in the list
        k = items[0]   # First is the key line 
        for i in items[1:]: # rest of items
            if d.haskey(i[:-1]): # is it in the dict
                 d[i].append(k)  # Add the k value

z.close()
print d
```

N.B. This is untested code but shouldn't be too far off.

Comment: Thanks! But what is "item"?